# Vaadin Application problems with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud, vaadin

My auto generated Vaadin 8 application is running fine on Google App Engine localhost, but when deployed on Google Cloud/Google App Engine, it shows the UI but I get the message Comunication Error, take note...., and the demo template is not working (clicking the button does nothing).

I create Vaadin 8 project, then convert it to Google App Engine Project in Eclipse.

This is my appengine-web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>

  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

This is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>OMABusinessAPI</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>OMABusinessAPI</name>

 <prerequisites>
  <maven>3</maven>
 </prerequisites>

 <properties>
  <vaadin.version>8.7.0</vaadin.version>
  <vaadin.plugin.version>8.7.0</vaadin.plugin.version>
  <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <!-- If there are no local customizations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
  <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
     <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>update-theme</goal>
       <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
       <goal>compile</goal>
       <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
       <goal>compile-theme</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
    <configuration>
     <filesets>
      <fileset>
       <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
       <includes>
        <include>**/styles.css</include>
        <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
       </includes>
      </fileset>
     </filesets>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
    running jetty:run on the command line. -->
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
     <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <profiles>
  <profile>
   <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
   <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
   </activation>

   <repositories>
    <repository>
     <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
     <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
     <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
     <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
     <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
    </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
     <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
     <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
     <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
     <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
     <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

</project>
```

And here is the auto generated Vaadin UI:

```js
package com.example.OMABusinessAPI;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window 
 * (or tab) or some part of an HTML page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be 
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        
        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thanks " + name.getValue() 
                    + ", it works!"));
        });
        
        layout.addComponents(name, button);
        
        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Looks like vaadin 8 is not supported on GAE https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16229159  and https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16842108/google-app-engine-vaadin-communication-problem-take-note-of-any-unsaved

Comment: I had similar issue using Vaadin 13 (customized simple html + base starter) deployed on Google App Engine. Links / Router works properly but one page with many components keeps reloading. Sample: http://tricera-chatbot.appspot.com